# Should a simple factory method include the "new" operation?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, factory-method

For example, suppose I have a class to create a button with specific styles common to my app, I can have either

1. Return a new modified object:

   ```java
   public class ButtonFactory {
       public static Button createAppButton(String st, int fontSize) {
           Button b = new Button();
           b.setColor(...);
           b.setText(...);
           b.playAnimation(...);
           return b;
       }
   }
   .
   .
   .
   Button b = ButtonFactory.createAppButton("test", 15);
   ```
2. Modify exist button from outside:

   ```java
   public class ButtonFactory {
       public static void modifyAppButton(Button b, String st, int fontSize){
           b.setColor(...);
           b.setText(...);
           b.playAnimation(...);
       }
   }
   .
   .
   .
   Button b = new Button();
   ButtonFactory.modifyAppButton(b, "test", 15);
   ```

Which one should I use?

Comment: I cannot see any advantage of the second method over the first, or indeed why you are using a factory pattern at all.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A factory by definition constructs things.

You should always name things based on what they do so that other programmers are not surprised by your code's behaviour.

Both of these classes are potentially useful, but if you called it a factory then it should construct and return instances

Answer (score 1):

- only the first class is a factory.
- More importantly, I would not make the factory creator method static (or at least not call it that way). Unless you actually instantiate some object with an interface or use some other generic programming mechanism, this is a pointless ineffective use of the factory pattern. You need to be able to change factories somehow. A better representation for a factory would be a FUNCTION OBJECT (e.g. https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1) or `std::function<>` (in C++). That way, you can EITHER use a static function (most common case) - or a bound function (with data).

Consider some stylistic pattern for your buttons, like background color, shape, or some such. You could have this DEFAULT in your DEFAULT factory. But you could have different factories that fill in different defaults (maybe based on user settings).

If your button factory was an object, the default might be the one you provided in your example. But you could invoke the same code with a new factory that generated different values for those unspecified parameters.

Comment: It looks to me you didn't fully understand the concept of a factory method (neither did the OP). Factory methods must be static, otherwise it's a constructor, and has nothing to do with factory. And `new` is a very bad choice for a method name.

Comment: Factories need not be static methods. They can (and frequently are) objects that can be invoked as functions.@Aganju  For example, consider if you're factory needs access to some data? Like maybe it gathers objects created into a pool (for some sort of management). Maybe you will want multiple pools (say with different security requirements etc). There are lots of reasons to have data bound to your factory object. (example: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1)

Comment: I understand 'factory' as 'factory pattern', where you don't know upfront the class that is requested, and the factory decides the object class based on a string or other input. are we talking about different things?

Comment: We are talking about the same pattern (at least roughly). I just see it a little more generally than you do. I tried to clarify my POST so it maybe makes more sense. The key think you appear to be missing, is that its useful to have DATA bound to the function object (sometimes - and by function object I mean the factory). Think about how that would work with your approach, and think about how it works with mine.@Aganju

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) pattern instead.  Establish the properties you'd generally want in a button, and then use it as a template for all others.

A factory method would only be useful here if you had several different types to choose from (and *abstract* factory if said creation itself was wildly different one from the next).  Since you're producing a single Button, factory is probably unnecessary here.